# zipfile writing .zip output to .py file location

Tags: python, python-zipfile

The following script is writing a zip into the directory where the .py file is located, but I need it to write it to the same location as the original folder.

I am suspecting it has something to do with the functionality of the zipfile.ZipFile object, but I can't seem to resolve the issue.   Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
import sys, zipfile, os, traceback, Tkinter, tkFileDialog

def zipws(path, zip, keep):
    path = os.path.normpath(path)
    print("Zipping {}...".format(path))

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):

        for file in filenames:

            if not file.endswith('.lock'):
                try:
                    if keep:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file), os.path.join(os.path.basename(path), os.path.join(dirpath, file)[len(path)+len(os.sep):]))
                    else:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file), os.path.join(dirpath[len(path):], file))

                except Exception, e:
                    print("    Error adding {}: {}".format(file, e))

    return None

try:
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    getGDBLoc = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="C:", title='Select the folder which contains the GDBs to be zipped')
    root.attributes('-topmost', False)
    wkPath = os.path.abspath(getGDBLoc).replace("\\","/")
    root.destroy()

    for fldr in os.listdir(wkPath):
        if fldr.endswith('.gdb'):
            outfile = fldr+".zip"
            try:
                zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                zipws(os.path.join(wkPath,fldr), zip, False)
                zip.close()
                print("  >> {} zipped successfully".format(outfile))

            except RuntimeError:
                if os.path.exists(outfile):
                        os.unlink(outfile)
                zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
                zipws(os.path.join(wkPath,fldr), zip, False)
                zip.close()
                print("  >> {} zipped, however unable to compress zip file contents.".format(outfile))

except:

    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    print("PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n{}\nError Info:\n    {}: {}\n".format(tbinfo, sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. As expected, my problem was when I created the zipfile.ZipFile object.  Outfile needed to be a full path location, not just output file name.

Changed these lines:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

To this:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(wkPath,outfile), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

I swear I tried this before and it didn't work, but it is working now.